# Casting issue with generic list

Tags: .net, list, casting

In the following code compilation error occurs but I can't understand why.

```
class RealMock<TEntity> : DataContext
{
    public RealMock():base("")
    {

    }

    public List<TEntity> inMemoryDataStore = new List<TEntity>();
    public List<TEntity> GetTable<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return inMemoryDataStore;  //Compilation error       
    }
}
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because your GetTable method in parametrized, try defining it as

```
public List<TEntity> GetTable () {...}
```